# SRM32H743 signed DFU updates

Tags: stm32, programming, security

I want to implement signed software updates to my MCU. It is connected via USB and I am using the USB DFU to upload a firmware to it.

I want only signed firmware to be allowed to be uploaded to the device; if possible, I also want to disallow reading of the firmware.

What is the standard way to implement this on the MCU level?

Answer (score 2):

The "standard" way is to sign your update with a private signing certificate and then validate that signature with the public key in your MCU-based system.

As I recall, some STM32 versions have built-in crypto hardware that supports RSA which would be a reasonable choice.

Comment: H743 has no crypto hardware. And the built-in DFU simply can upload whatever anyone wants to upload. Might be possible with custom bootloader that re-implements DFU.

Comment: I need the DFU to disallow unsigned flashing, if it doesn't I can just flash it and bypass it

Comment: @justme the DFU is in the ROM so I guess you can't overwrite it

Comment: @UrielKatz No, it can't be overwritten, but you can make your own bootloader that acts as a DFU device and then enable the readout protection.

Comment: But if I can restart the device and assert BOOT0 then I can bypass the bootloader and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to accept the entire firmware image into the device before you can check the signature (sign with private key, check signature with public key).  Not sure how much RAM / flash that chip has.

Doesn't matter if the MCU doesn't have H/W crypto -- there are plenty of software libraries that can do it, it will just be slower.  ECC is faster and smaller than RSA for most things, but for your exact use case -- verifying a digital signature -- RSA will be faster than ECC for comparable key strength.

The standard USB DFU doesn't do this, so as others said you'll need to write your own.  ST provides a package called "[SBSFU](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-sbsfu.html)" that should handle this.

Going forward (future designs) the STM32L5 has ECC & RSA H/W acceleration.

Comment: The question is how you accept the firmware into the device but prevent it from booting.

I saw SBSFU but it is quite complex and doesn't answer the question how you can't bypassit

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand your question.  The update and the booting are 2 entirely different things.  You can change the SBSFU code, if the signature doesn't match you don't have to accept the firmware and boot into it.  yes SBSFU is complex I agree, but secure bootloaders often are.  By the way, usually a secure firmware update is implemented /in/ (or by) the bootloader -- the product reboots into the bootloader, receives the update, and accepts it or rejects it, and then reboots.

Comment: Also I'm not familiar with the term "reading" of the firmware.  Do you mean execution?  Because to check the digital signature of the firmware, you must "read" it to calculate a hash and verify the signature.  Like I said, to me your question and your needs aren't clear.  You seem to be confused by the booting process, but the signature needs to be checked not just on receiving the firmware, but at each boot.  I'd suggest reading up on secure boot.

Comment: The issue I see is that the DFU bootloader of the STM32 is in the ROM and thus can't be replaced.
If I enable access to DFU mode (my host device has a pin to control the BOOT0 of the STM32) then it means that no matter what I put into the STM32 after the bootloader you can erase/override it. unless there is HW support for verification/write lock/etc. this is what I am missing in my understanding

Comment: @UrielKatz - you are correct, you cannot replace or overwrite the ROM DFU.  But you can choose to boot from your own flash memory instead.  Section 2.6 of the Reference Guide ("Boot Configuration") explains this; by setting the value of the BOOT pin at POR, you can determine if BOOT_ADD0 or BOOT_ADD1 is used; BOOT_ADD0 by default boots from the bottom of flash.  You can also re-program the flash option bytes (BOOT_ADD0/1) if your hardware can't be changed.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @UrielKatz - sorry one other thing that I forgot to mention -- see section 4.5.3 of the Reference Guide ("Readout Protection (RDP)") - it explains how, by using mode 1 or mode 2, you can prevent an attacker from reading out flash memory.  In Mode 1, an attacker can erase, but not read out, your code in flash (well, really all of flash) via the debug interface; in Mode 2, an attacker cannot even erase flash.  Of course, even these hardware protections might have vulnerabilities via glitching, FIB, etc. but let's leave those for now.

Answer (score 0):

The two goals are orthogonal. Reading of the firmware is one thing, and to protect against that you need a solid bootloader that won't have holes easy to bypass, and also solid firmware that won't have vulnerabilities that result in code injection. You also can't use a device that has an insecure bootloader embedded in ROM - you need to choose another device for that!

Requiring signed firmware is another kettle of fish. I consider indiscriminate use of signed firmware unethical. If there's no way to bypass it, you're contributing to e-waste and waste of resources. Even for obscure devices there may be hobbyists who'll want to repurpose them and perhaps load their own firmware to extend the life of the device somehow.

Signed firmware is OK as long as you leave a way to completely wipe the device so that only a non-secure bootloader remains - basically with all the code that did signature verification and encryption removed, and from then on unsigned firmware only can be used. That way nobody can pretend they used your firmware when they really didn't, since it'll be irreversible, and the warranty and manual can clearly exclude support and liability from the on and it'll be only fair.

You'd probably want to not only have the firmware signed, but also keep a private decryption key (for public key crypto shield around AES key) in the bootloader, or in secure key storage if the SoC you use has one, so the genuine firmware would be properly encrypted to make it harder to find exploitable flaws in it.